# make sure the same event listener is not added more than once

Tags: actionscript-3

I am implementing a singleton `IEventDispatcher` class but ran into a problem that sometimes I add the same event listener function to my instance multiple times. I tried keeping an array of the `eventFunctions` as follows to not add the event more than once but it does not seem to be working as expected.

```
private var eventFunctions:Array =[];

    public function addEventListener(type:String, listener:Function, useCapture:Boolean = false, priority:int = 0, useWeakReference:Boolean = false):void {
    if(dispatcher.hasEventListener(type) && eventFunctions.indexOf(listener) > -1){
        trace("adding event listener that already exists " + type + " with function " + listener);
        return;
    }

    dispatcher.addEventListener(type, listener,  useCapture, priority, useWeakReference);
}
```

Comment: you don't seem to ever populate the array? among other things.  Is there more to this then what you've shown?    What if you had multiple events that callback the same function?   This method also negates the benefit of weak references.

Comment: I suggest to only track events/listeners when useweakreference = false. That is quite important. I personally use Object to track event types (since they are all string) then store in my Object keys a Vector.<Function> . I also bypass the system when useweakreference and usecapture are true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First as a note, there is no issue with adding a listener more than once - so long as the object/dispatcher, the callback function, and the useCapture parameter are identical, it will not actually add another listener.

For example:

```
bob.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
bob.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler, false);

function clickHandler(e:Event):void {  trace("clicky"); };
```

Will only produce 1 trace per click.

Now, if you changed it to:

```
bob.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler, false);
bob.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler, true); //<-- use capture is true on this one
```

Now you will get two traces per click.

Now, if besides this first point, you still have a need to track all your listeners in a singleton, I'd suggest doing something like this:

```
//instead of an array, use a dictionary so you can have weak keys that don't prevent your objects from being garbage collected
private static var listeners:Dictionary = new Dictionary(true);

//you need to pass the dispatcher into the function (missing from your question code)
public function addEventListener(dispatcher:EventDispatcher, type:String, listener:Function, useCapture:Boolean = false, priority:int = 0, useWeakReference:Boolean = false):void {

    //check is there a record in the dictionary for this object (array)
    if(listeners[dispatcher]){

        //loop through the array and see if there are any matches
        for(var i:int=0;i<listeners[dispatcher].length;i++){
            if(listeners[dispatcher][i] && listeners[dispatcher][i].listener == listener
                && listeners[dispatcher][i].type == type 
                && listeners[dispatcher][i].useCapture == useCapture
                && listeners[dispatcher][i].useWeakReference == useWeakReference){

                trace("adding event listener that already exists " + type + " with function " + listener);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    //add the listener to the dispatcher
    dispatcher.addEventListener(type, listener,  useCapture, priority, useWeakReference);

    //if no record exists yet, create the array and associate it with this dispatcher
    if(!listeners[dispatcher]) listeners[dispatcher] = new Array();

    //add the parameters just used to the array.
    listeners[dispatcher].push({listener: listener, useCapture: useCapture, useWeakReference: useWeakReference});
}

//you will need a way to remove the listeners as well
public function removeEventListener(dispatcher:EventDispatcher, type:String, listener:Function, useCapture:Boolean = false):void {
    if(listeners[dispatcher] && listeners[dispatcher].length > 0){

        //loop through the array and see if there any matches
        for(var i:int=0;i<listeners[dispatcher].length;i++){
            if(listeners[dispatcher][i] && listeners[dispatcher][i].listener == listener
                && listeners[dispatcher][i].type == type 
                && listeners[dispatcher][i].useCapture == useCapture){

                //remove the event form the dispatcher
                dispatcher.removeEventListener(type, listener, useCapture);

                //remove the item from the array
                listeners[dispatcher].splice(i,1);

                //if the array is now empty, remove the dictionary item
                if(listeners[dispatcher].length < 1) delete listeners[dispatcher];

                //exit the function now
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was all written off the top of my head, so it's untested and may have typos.

Comment: if you track event set with useweakreference = true you will break the useweakreference system. It's better to not touch event set with useweakreference = true (meaning do not track them at all)

Comment: accepting this as it answers the question posted. i did not understand my problem as well as i should have and it was not entirely related to what i posted but i have fixed it now.